# Opening a photo from a directory

Tags: python, image, directory, python-imaging-library

I am trying to open images from a kaggle dataset, which I have imported into my python program and have loaded
I am unable to open the photo, when I run the code it simply produces a blank space

I tried the following code below (this is a section of my wider code), yet it only produces a with

```
def loadImages(path):
    # return array of images

    imagesList = listdir(path)
    loadedImages = []
    for image in imagesList:
        img = PImage.open(path + image)
        loadedImages.append(img)

    return loadedImages
path = "embryo-classification-based-on-microscopic-images/test/0/"

imgs = loadImages(path)
for img in imgs:
  img.show()
```

Comment: How do you run your code?

Comment: I run my code on python, using google colab

Comment: if it is useful, I can attach the colab link?

Comment: Might be, can't say. Seeing you use a relative path (supposedly to your source file), I wanted to make sure the working directory is correct. Otherwise the path would not be found. Happens a lot. You can use `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'your', 'relative', 'path')` to make sure.

Comment: first you should check in what folder it runs code - `os.getcwd()` (it gets `Current Working Directory`). Or use `listdir('.')` to check if you have your folder `embryo-classification-based-on-microscopic-images` in current folder. Or you should use `absolute` path instead of `relative` path - `/full/path/to/embryo-classification-based-on-microscopic-images/test/0/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone had a solution on a website, I filled in the information in the code, and it was this:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import os

def load(path):
    # Return array of images
    imagesList = os.listdir(path)
    loadedImages = []
    for image in imagesList:
        img_path = os.path.join(path, image)
        img = Image.open(img_path)
        loadedImages.append(img)
    return loadedImages

path = "embryo-classification-based-on-microscopic-images/test/0/"
imgs = load(path)

# Display images using matplotlib
for img in imgs:
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.axis('off')  # Hide axis
    plt.show()
```

The dataset path is inserted in the load function so it contains the image.
Use matplotlib to display, if any problem happens, please tell me to edit my answer, thank you!